# Firefox running infinitely even after condition met in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following function is called with

```
setTimeout(function () { get_progress(fileID,fileName)},8000);
```

upon a form submit. The purpose of the function is to get read_file.php to read a txt file that stores the file upload status from a form (in percentage).

Upon reaching 80%, my Firefox seems to run infinitely even when HEAD returns an error. Am I have too many recursions or have I used a wrong condition that's causing get_progress to run repeatedly even when filename does not exist in the folder ?

```
function get_progress( fileID, filename) {
$.ajax({
    url: filename,
    type: 'HEAD',
    success: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'read_file.php',
            data: 'filename=' +filename,
            success: function(html) {
                document.getElementById(fileID).innerHTML = html + ' <img src="images/loading.gif" />'
                setInterval(function() {get_progress(fileID,filename)},4000);
            }
        });
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each successful return from the AJAX call, you set up a completely new interval timer. After a few successes, there'll be a lot of those interval timers running. (Note that unlike `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()` establishes a timed routine that will run *over and over again* until the last syllable of recorded time.)

Oh, and each one calls "get_progress" again each time it runs.

So after the first call, there'll be one interval timer running. Four seconds later, it'll go again, and another interval timer will start. Four seconds later, **two** calls to "get_progress" will now be made, one by each interval timer handler. Great - now four seconds after that, there'll be **four** calls to "get_progress". And so on; after a minute or so there'll be thousands and thousands (I'm on vacation so I can't be bothered to do the exact math :-)

Instead of calling `setInterval()` in the ajax "success" handler, call `setTimeout()`.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I totally forgot about the infinite recursion that I had with setInterval.